# how to convert list to class 'django.db.models.query.QuerySet'

Tags: python, django, django-filter

I want to use django_filter, but my datatype is list.  it shows that list has no attribute model

```
myfiler1 = Orderfilter(request.GET, queryset=mylist)
```

I want to use django_filter, but my datatype is list.  it shows that list has no attribute model

```
myfiler1 = Orderfilter(request.GET, queryset=mylist)
```

so how to convert my list to `django.db.models.query.QuerySet`

Comment: Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18607698/how-to-convert-a-list-in-to-queryset-django and see if helps.

Comment: You should pass your queryset instead of converting it to a list. The list type and QuerySet are two types.

Comment: The best solution is to avoid making a list in the first place. Try real hard to achieve whatever logic you have through the ORM and resist the urge to filter in the more familiar Python. If that is not possible, you can always do the brutish `sq = MyModel.objects.filter(pk__in=[m.pk for m in mylist])` to convert it back to a queryset.

Comment: I have saw this above  their data is queryset but my original data type is a list. so is there anyway to convert  list to queryset?

Comment: queryset is so difficult to merge  or sum by columns, particular hard  for dirty data

Comment: sq = MyModel.objects.filter(pk__in=[m.pk for m in mylist])   I saw this, but this is also do something from a queryset, my original data is a list. so  what should I do

Comment: It doesn't exactly have to be `[m.pk for m in mylist]`, it depends on the structure of your list. Your goal is to pass a list of primary keys, for example it might be `[m["order_id"] for m in mylist]`

Comment: @ybl  it use the list as a primary keys,  so it also from a queryset.  but my original original data is a list.

Comment: @hld You can try to filter your original query set first, and then do other complex operations and convert it into a list

Comment: @hld What I mean is to use `django_filter` to filter your original queryset first, and then do other operations

Comment: and the final data is different with the orignial  querset, because  it merge another queryset. so i can't just use the list as a key to select from the original querset

Comment: @hld I have dealt with a situation similar to yours. I merged the query sets of different models, and then filtered their common fields. What I did at the time was to filter them separately using the same method, and then merge them.

Comment: can you tell me more

Comment: @hld It seems that you want to connect data outside the model to the queryset and filter it, so you can't use the filter in django, because it is based on the model, but these extra data are not in the model, there are two Two methods: 1. Add a new field in the model as the corresponding "count". 2. Manually filter the data list

Comment: @911 I think your said is right. I want to follow your first advice,  and I add a new field  to my model. but how can I MERGE this to my model?

Comment: @911我发现你的地址也是北京，谢谢你，我那蹩脚的英文。我就是想把一个字典，利用字典的关键字把字典的值对应到queryset上面。求指导

Comment: @hld 尴尬，我还一直用翻译来着，如果你这个字典不会一直变的话，你写个脚本就可以了，把字典里的值同步到模型上，如果他是动态的话，你只能自己实现筛选了

Comment: @911@ user2390182   thank you.  I maded it finally by using  .objects.filter and  .objects.bulk_update

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass **`orderdata = myfiler1.qs`**

```py
orderdata = OrdersModel.objects.filter(user=request.user)
myfiler1 = Orderfilter(request.GET, queryset=orderdata) 
orderdata = myfiler1.qs
```

Comment: true, but my orderdata is a list

Comment: you need must be  pass queryset in filter not list

Comment: yes I know, so how to convert my list to queryset

Comment: plz  update question with full code

Comment: I mean I want to see **mylist**

Comment: File "D:\anacon2022\lib\site-packages\django_filters\filterset.py", line 176, in __init__
    model = queryset.model
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'model'